# Is it better to have 2 smaller render targets or one large one?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am writing a deferred renderer, and am trying to pack my gbuffer.

Would it be better to store the diffuse and specular together:

```
vec4 difSpec = (diffuse.xyz, specular) // FORMAT_RGBA
gl_FragData[0] = difSpc;
```

or to use 2 render targets

```
vec3 diffuse
float specular
gl_FragData[0] = diffuse  // FORMAT_RGB
gl_FragData[1] = specular //  FORMAT_RED
```

The question is would one be better than the other and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lesser buffer bind/rebind operations you use - the better.

Even more, in your case you're good with just 4 floats: RGB+Specular. So use the full 128-bit rendertarget and pack the (r,g,b,specular) values. It must be better because the access to different memory locations (96 bits for rgb and 32 more for the specular) is bad for cache.

One render target is also better for the older videocards. Anyways, when you use only 96 bits you're wasting memory. The g-buffer always has to be tightly packed.

Comment: Ah, I take it that it is better to have fewer, larger gbuffers, so I could do RGBA32F texture r - depth, g - normal, b - diffuse, specular, a - emissive

r
g

Comment: Yes, at the bit-level you can pack normals even tighter to 10:10:10:1 or even 15:15:1 (z is calculated from the normalization condition). So just keep the data packed to avoid a lot of scattered memory reads.

Comment: +1 Could you give a quick example what the packing code would look like?

Comment: see the presentation for more details http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/01gdc09ad3ddstalkerclearsky210309.ppt

Comment: In the slides, they are using 1 RGBA16F and 1 RGBA8 render target instead of a single 128 bit render target, why is this so?

Comment: It was 3 or 4 years ago, the fillrate is an issue.